# Dijkstra's implementation in rust

Tags: beginner, rust, dijkstra

I would like to get any feedback about my implementation of Dijkstra algorithm in Rust following this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pVfj6mxhdMw).

Please be aware that this my first code in Rust as well as my first Dijkstra implementation in any language.

```
type Vertex = char;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Connection {
    peers   : (Vertex, Vertex),
    weight  : u32,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Graph {
    connections : Vec<Connection>,
    vertices    : Vec<Vertex>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Road {
    vertex     : Vertex,
    distance   : u32,
    via_vertex : Vertex,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
#[derive(Clone)]
struct DijkstraTable {
    start_vertex : Vertex,
    roads        : Vec<Road>,
    unvisited    : Vec<Vertex>,
}

impl DijkstraTable {
    fn get_distance(&self, vertex: Vertex) -> u32 {
        let mut ret = 0;

        for r in &self.roads {
            if r.vertex == vertex {
                ret = r.distance;
            }
        }

        ret
    }

    fn get_road_mut(&mut self, vertex: &Vertex) -> Option<&mut Road> {
        for r in &mut self.roads {
            if r.vertex == *vertex {
                return Some(r);
            }
        }

        None
    }

    fn get_road(&self, vertex: &Vertex) -> Option<&Road> {
        for r in &self.roads {
            if r.vertex == *vertex {
                return Some(r);
            }
        }

        None
    }

    fn get_next_unvisited(&self) -> Option<&Vertex> {
        let mut min = u32::MAX;
        let mut next = None;

        for v in &self.unvisited {
            match self.get_road(&v) {
                None => break,
                Some(r) => {
                    if r.distance < min {
                        min = r.distance;
                        next = Some(v);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        next
    }

    fn remove(&mut self, v : &Vertex) {
        let mut index = 0;
        while index < self.unvisited.len() {
            let toremove = &self.unvisited[index];
            if v == toremove {
                self.unvisited.remove(index);
                break
            }
            index += 1;
        }
    }
}

impl Road {
    fn new(from: Vertex) -> Road {
        Road {
            vertex      : from,
            distance    : u32::MAX,
            via_vertex  : '-',
        }
    }
}

impl Graph {
    fn get_weight(&self, peers: (Vertex, Vertex)) -> u32 {
        let mut ret : u32 = 0;

        for c in &self.connections {
            let (a, b) = peers;

            if c.peers == peers || c.peers == (b, a) {
                ret = c.weight;
                break;
            }
        }
        ret
    }

    fn get_neighbours(&self, vertex: &Vertex) -> Vec<&Vertex> {
        let mut neighbours : Vec<&Vertex> = Vec::new();

        for c in &self.connections {
            if c.peers.0 == *vertex {
                neighbours.push(&c.peers.1);
            } else if c.peers.1 == *vertex {
                neighbours.push(&c.peers.0);
            }
        }

        neighbours
    }

    fn vertices_from_connections(conns : &Vec<Connection>) -> Vec<Vertex> {
        let mut verts : Vec<Vertex> = Vec::new();

        for c in conns.iter() {
            if ! verts.contains(&c.peers.0) {
                verts.push(c.peers.0);
            }
            if ! verts.contains(&c.peers.1) {
                verts.push(c.peers.1);
            }
        }
        verts
    }

    fn new(conns: Vec<Connection>) -> Graph {
        Graph {
            vertices    : Graph::vertices_from_connections(&conns),
            connections : conns,
        }
    }

    fn dijkstra(&self, start: Vertex) -> DijkstraTable {
        let mut table = DijkstraTable {
            start_vertex : start,
            roads        : Vec::new(),
            unvisited    : self.vertices.clone(),
        };

        for v in &self.vertices {
            let mut road = Road::new(*v);

            if v == &start {
                road.distance = 0;
            }

            table.roads.push(road);
        }

        loop {
            let xx = table.clone();
            match xx.get_next_unvisited() {
                None => break,
                Some(v) => {
                    //println!("{}##################",v);
                    for n in self.get_neighbours(v) {
                        match table.get_road_mut(n) {
                            None => println!("Error"),
                            Some(rn) => {
                                let d = self.get_weight((*v, *n));
                                let k = d + xx.get_distance(*v);
                                if k < rn.distance {
                                    rn.via_vertex = *v;
                                    rn.distance = k;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    table.remove(v);
                    //println!(" {:#?} ", table);
                }
            }
        }

        table
    }
}

fn main() {
    let graph = Graph::new(
        vec![
            Connection {
                peers: ('A', 'B'),
                weight: 6,
            },
            Connection {
                peers: ('A', 'D'),
                weight: 1,
            },
            Connection {
                peers: ('D', 'E'),
                weight: 1,
            },
            Connection {
                peers: ('D', 'B'),
                weight: 2,
            },
            Connection {
                peers: ('E', 'B'),
                weight: 2,
            },
            Connection {
                peers: ('E', 'C'),
                weight: 5,
            },
            Connection {
                peers: ('B', 'C'),
                weight: 5,
            },
        ]
    );

    println!(" Dijkstra of 'A': {:#?}", graph.dijkstra('A'));

}
```

**Edit**:

The code and feedbacks are pushed to [this github repo](https://github.com/zskdan/rust-dijkstra).

Answer (score 2):

Many of your methods can be simplified (?) with iterators.  Here's a few examples:

---

```
fn get_distance(&self, vertex: Vertex) -> u32 {
    let mut ret = 0;

    for r in &self.roads {
        if r.vertex == vertex {
            ret = r.distance;
        }
    }

    ret
}
```

becomes

```
fn get_distance(&self, vertex: Vertex) -> u32 {
    self.roads
        .iter()
        .rev()
        .find(|road| road.vertex == vertex)
        .map(|road| road.distance)
        .unwrap_or(0)
}
```

---

```
fn get_road_mut(&mut self, vertex: &Vertex) -> Option<&mut Road> {
    for r in &mut self.roads {
        if r.vertex == *vertex {
            return Some(r);
        }
    }

    None
}
```

becomes

```
fn get_road_mut(&mut self, vertex: &Vertex) -> Option<&mut Road> {
    self.roads
        .iter_mut()
        .find(|road| road.vertex == vertex)
}
```

---

```
fn remove(&mut self, v : &Vertex) {
    let mut index = 0;
    while index < self.unvisited.len() {
        let toremove = &self.unvisited[index];
        if v == toremove {
            self.unvisited.remove(index);
            break
        }
        index += 1;
    }
}
```

becomes

```
fn remove(&mut self, v: &Vertex) {
    let index = self.unvisited.iter().position(|vertex| vertex == v);
    if let Some(index) = index {
        self.unvisited.remove(index);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @L.F. now the code looks more rust idiomatic.

Comment: The new `remove()` code trig a compilation issue since `iterator::position` return an `Option`. So I had to adapt it to: 
`match self.unvisited.iter().position(|vertex| vertex==v) {
            None => (), 
            Some(index) => {
                self.unvisited.remove(index); 
            }
        }`

Comment: @Zskdan That's right.  I've modified the code.

Comment: I'm not sure of understanding the syntax of the new code: Does `let Some(index) = index` is handled as condition which return `False` in case of `index == None` and `True` otherwise?

Comment: Yes. `if let` is a control flow that works the way you described - enter the block if the `let` binding matches.

Answer (score 1):

The call to clone() in Graph::dijkstra feels wrong. Without actually re-factoring the code, I am not sure of the solution, I can see you have some problems with borrowing / mut.

My intuition is that you need to make the method that constructs DijkstraTable a method of DijkstraTable rather than Graph. It would take a (non-mutable) reference to the Graph.

Edit:

After taking a much closer look, I made some changes to eliminate the cloning ( the #derive(Clone)s are no longer needed ), and other changes:

```
type Vertex = char;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Connection {
    peers   : (Vertex, Vertex),
    weight  : u32,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Graph {
    connections : Vec<Connection>,
    vertices    : Vec<Vertex>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Road {
    vertex     : Vertex,
    distance   : u32,
    via_vertex : Vertex,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct DijkstraTable {
    start_vertex : Vertex,
    roads        : Vec<Road>,
    unvisited    : Vec<Vertex>,
}

impl DijkstraTable {
    fn get_distance(&self, vertex: Vertex) -> u32 {
        let mut ret = 0;

        for r in &self.roads {
            if r.vertex == vertex {
                ret = r.distance;
            }
        }

        ret
    }

    fn get_next_unvisited(&self) -> Option<Vertex> {
        let mut min = u32::MAX;
        let mut next = None;

        for vertex in &self.unvisited {
            for r in &self.roads
            {
              if r.vertex == *vertex 
              {
                if r.distance < min {
                  min = r.distance;
                  next = Some(*vertex);
                }
              }
            }
        }
        next
    }

    fn remove(&mut self, v : Vertex) {
        let mut index = 0;
        while index < self.unvisited.len() {
            let toremove = self.unvisited[index];
            if v == toremove {
                self.unvisited.remove(index);
                break
            }
            index += 1;
        }
    }


    fn new( graph: &Graph, start: Vertex ) -> DijkstraTable {
        let mut table = DijkstraTable {
            start_vertex : start,
            roads        : Vec::new(),
            unvisited    : graph.vertices.clone(),
        };

        for v in &graph.vertices {
            let mut road = Road::new(*v);

            if *v == start {
                road.distance = 0;
            }

            table.roads.push(road);
        }

        loop {
            match table.get_next_unvisited() {
                None => break,
                Some(v) => {
                    //println!("{}##################",v);

                    for n in graph.get_neighbours(v) {
                      let d = graph.get_weight((v, n));
                      let k = d + table.get_distance(v);
                      for road in &mut table.roads
                      {         
                        if road.vertex == n
                        {
                          if k < road.distance {
                            road.via_vertex = v;
                            road.distance = k;
                          }
                          break;
                        }
                      }
                    }
                    table.remove(v);
                    // println!(" {:#?} ", table);
                }
            }
        }
        table
    }
}

impl Road {
    fn new(from: Vertex) -> Road {
        Road {
            vertex      : from,
            distance    : u32::MAX,
            via_vertex  : '-',
        }
    }
}

impl Graph {
    fn get_weight(&self, peers: (Vertex, Vertex)) -> u32 {
        let mut ret : u32 = 0;

        for c in &self.connections {
            let (a, b) = peers;

            if c.peers == peers || c.peers == (b, a) {
                ret = c.weight;
                break;
            }
        }
        ret
    }

    fn get_neighbours(&self, vertex: Vertex) -> Vec<Vertex> {
        let mut neighbours : Vec<Vertex> = Vec::new();

        for c in &self.connections {
            if c.peers.0 == vertex {
                neighbours.push(c.peers.1);
            } else if c.peers.1 == vertex {
                neighbours.push(c.peers.0);
            }
        }

        neighbours
    }

    fn vertices_from_connections(conns : &Vec<Connection>) -> Vec<Vertex> {
        let mut verts : Vec<Vertex> = Vec::new();

        for c in conns.iter() {
            if ! verts.contains(&c.peers.0) {
                verts.push(c.peers.0);
            }
            if ! verts.contains(&c.peers.1) {
                verts.push(c.peers.1);
            }
        }
        verts
    }

    fn new(conns: Vec<Connection>) -> Graph {
        Graph {
            vertices    : Graph::vertices_from_connections(&conns),
            connections : conns,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let graph = Graph::new(
        vec![
            Connection {
                peers: ('A', 'B'),
                weight: 6,
            },
            Connection {
                peers: ('A', 'D'),
                weight: 1,
            },
            Connection {
                peers: ('D', 'E'),
                weight: 1,
            },
            Connection {
                peers: ('D', 'B'),
                weight: 2,
            },
            Connection {
                peers: ('E', 'B'),
                weight: 2,
            },
            Connection {
                peers: ('E', 'C'),
                weight: 5,
            },
            Connection {
                peers: ('B', 'C'),
                weight: 5,
            },
        ]
    );
    let dt = DijkstraTable::new( &graph, 'A' );
    println!(" Dijkstra of 'A': {:#?}", dt );
}
```

I ought ideally to explain the changes in more detail, but I hope the above helps. In particular you had functions returning &Vertex rather than simply Vertex, which I think caused problems. Also, I have eliminated the functions get_road_mut and get_road. I'm not sure if this was strictly necessary or not, but having functions that return references is I think generally problematic.

Edit 2:

It is possible to have a function get_road that returns a mutable reference:

```
fn get_road(&mut self,  n: Vertex) -> &mut Road
{
  for road in &mut self.roads
  {         
    if road.vertex == n { return road; }
  }
  panic!("Road not found");
}
```

Which is used like this:

```
                  let road = table.get_road( n );
                  if k < road.distance {
                    road.via_vertex = v;
                    road.distance = k;
                  }
```

Besides, since we have a keyed set of values, it may be easier to use a [Hash Map](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch08-03-hash-maps.html).

Comment: Indeed I was forced to do the `clone()` to handle ownership issues (Cannot borrow as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable).
I think you're right, It seems now (After reading your comment) obvious that I should move `dijkstra()` method to `DijkstraTable`.
I'll try that. Thanks @George for your feedback.

Comment: Your changes makes the code more clear and clean. In fact I still don't feel comfortable with references. And when should I return references.
With `get_road_mut` and `get_road` I was hoping to factorize them in a single call. But this seems not possible since they are returning different object type.
Can you please elaborate on why having functions that return references is problematic ?

Comment: The reason is that the lifetime of the return value will be limited, also returning a mutable reference ( allowing part of a struct to be modified ) feels not quite right to me, but it is possible, see my latest edit to my answer above.

Comment: My understanding of returning references is that the lifetime will be rather guaranteed by the compiler. 
And they may be helpful to avoid wasting memory on copying the object -like returning pointer in C- (so it worth it for Road object but not for Vertex(char)).